# jQuery .append() function doesn't insert to DIV

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't `drawUploader()` append `html` to the `div` `drawUploader` ?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax File Upload</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawUploader()
{

    $("#drawUploader").append("<div id=\"upload_wrapper\">"+
                             "<form id=\"upload\" name=\"upload\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data' method='post' action='index.php' target='upload_target'>"+
                             "<input name='uploaded_file' type='file' size='30' id='uploaded_file'  />"+
                             "<input id='sent' name='sent' type='submit'  value='Upload' />"+
                             "</form>"+
                             "</div>"+
                             "<div id='loading' style='background:url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat left; height:50px; width:370px; display:none;'>"+
                             "<p style='margin-left:40px; padding-top:15px;'>Uploading File... Please wait</p>"+
                             "</div>"+
                             "<div id='image_wrapper' style='display:none;'><img id='preview' src='' /></div>"
                            );
}       
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="drawUploader()" value="start uplaod"  />
<div id="drawUploader"></div>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:10px; height:10px; display:none"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it to instead?

Comment: You should really consider moving to a template pattern here. Then simply call `$('#myTemplate').clone()` to create a new instance of the  HTML and insert it.

Comment: Change append to `html`, see if that works.. By the way, if you need to append it because you want multiple upload wrappers, you should use class instead of ID's since you can only use an ID once.

Comment: It's an example selector. You really had to ask that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a mismatched quote in your form attributes. try this:

```
function drawUploader() {
    $("#drawUploader").append("<div id=\"upload_wrapper\">" + "<form id=\"upload\" name=\"upload\" enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='index.php' target='upload_target'>" + "<input name='uploaded_file' type='file' size='30' id='uploaded_file'  />" + "<input id='sent' name='sent' type='submit'  value='Upload' />" + "</form>" + "</div>" + "<div id='loading' style='background:url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat left; height:50px; width:370px; display:none;'>" + "<p style='margin-left:40px; padding-top:15px;'>Uploading File... Please wait</p>" + "</div>" + "<div id='image_wrapper' style='display:none;'><img id='preview' src='' /></div>");
}
```

the error was on the enctype attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` element is malformed. If you use the dev tools in Chrome you would have seen that the `<div>` upload_wrapper was being added but not the rest.

Change all the `\"` to single `'` and it works fine.